# Flutter Application won't install on Xiomi, OnePlus, Vivo and user session is not maintained

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, usersession

I have recently developed a Flutter application which works totally fine on all iPhone models and tested on Samsung and different android devices. However it gives either one of the following issue on some phones such as OnePlus, Xiomi Redmi etc.

1. Application won't install with error message "There was a problem in parsing the package"
2. If by chance the app gets installed on some Xiomi, OnePlus models, my user session which I have maintained through shared preferences does not persist. User is logged out when the app has been closed.

I am using following packages in my application:
[list of packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ONJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly due to Android 12 and incorrect AndroidManifest.xml configuration if the phone i running SDK 31+ insure your app is configured for Android 12 if not try to set android:exported to any , ,, or  components that have s declared in the app’s AndroidManifest.xml

[Here is a blog on how to fix it](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lets-be-explicit-about-our-intent-filters-c5dbe2dbdce0)